# Query for specific Azure AD permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way in Microsoft Graph how to check whether signed-in user (device code auth is used) has a specific AAD permission? In my case that would be Microsoft.Directory/groups/members/update - I'd like to notify a user that he/she is not permitted to add service principal to an AD group.

My initial idea was to find DirectoryRoles a user is member of. Then view related DirectoryRoleTemplates and somehow check permissions attached to the template. It looks like this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Microsoft has not exposed an API for obtaining Role permissions corresponding to DirectoryRole.

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#role-permissions), `microsoft.directory/groups/members/update` permission only exists in the following roles:

- Directory Writers
- Groups Administrator
- User Account Administrator
- Intune Service Administrator
- Partner Tier1 Support
- Partner Tier2 Support

A workaround is to customize a config file in your project to set the fixed values. Read them to see if the user's directory role matches one of them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a program manager at Microsoft working on Azure AD access control. Thanks for your question and feedback. As Allen says, we don't have an API for this today. The best we have is what's called the 'wids' claim in the user's access token. Search [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims) article for 'wids' for more information.

The wids claim contains the list of directory role template object ids the user is a member of. Role template object ids are immutable and consistent across the system, so you can hardcode your check against them. There is a role to template id mapping table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#role-template-ids).

We're looking at exposing an API that returns the list of underlying permissions of the signed-in user following the syntax Allen mentions from the documentation. However, I don't have a date yet on when that would be available.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks again,
Vince Smith

Comment: Thank you for additional comment, Vince. May I ask if there is any task (maybe on GitHub?) where we can track progress on exposing such API?

Comment: What are the template object ids you mentioned here used for?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the JWT token you can look at that "wids" attribute that will contain the IDs of the assigned Entra Roles.

There are some good instructions on how to do that [here](https://easy365.io/how-to-check-the-permissions-of-your-microsoft-graph-application-via-jwt-0e0e7d6af68d)